# Is there a plugin or resource for custom implementation for OAUTH and regular user login?

Tags: plugins, users, login, user-registration, oauth

I have two sets of users. Internal users just exist in a black box I can authenticate using OAUTH. I also have public "randos" that will be mostly scammers & spammers that I need to have register and then also allow them to log in-- a few actual users may sign up and buy something from the woocommerce store, that remains to be seen.

Does anyone know of plugins that exist for handling my internal and external users?

Alternatively, there is the idea of extending a class and hijacking the login by overriding certain functions.

I have tried nothing and am all out of ideas. My google searches are not helping me.

So, would be grateful for possible plugins, or a gut check on my plan b of rolling my own, and/or help with better search terms to go hunting answers with.